# Trying to implement object-oriented pong game

Tags: python, oop

I am trying to follow the [freecodecamp python pong game tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XGf2GcyHPhc&t=1845s). However with an object oriented approach instead of a linear one.

I created an object that both the paddles and the ball would be derived from. I wanted all of the functions to be easily accessible and manageable. However when updating the balls position and pressing a key it is also moving the paddings positions as well. I am not sure why because the objects should not have anything to do with each other. its like one object is manipulating another. if anybody could assist in helping me figure out the issue that would be greatly appreciated

```
import turtle

class PongObj:
    score = 0
    speed = 0
    position = [0, 0]
    direction = [0, 0]
    shape = 0

    def __init__(self, _x, _y, _wid=5, _len=1, _dir=0) -> object:
        self.shape = turtle.Turtle()
        self.shape.speed(self.speed)
        self.shape.shape("square")
        self.shape.color("white")
        self.shape.shapesize(stretch_wid=_wid, stretch_len=_len)
        self.shape.penup()
        self.set_location(_x, _y)
        self.direction[0] = self.direction[1] = _dir

    def set_speed(self, n_speed):
        self.speed = n_speed

    def set_location(self, _x, _y):
        self.position[0] = _x
        self.position[1] = _y
        self.shape.goto(self.position[0], self.position[1])

    def update_coordinates(self):
        self.position[1] = self.shape.ycor()
        self.position[0] = self.shape.xcor()

    def object_up(self):
        self.position[1] += 20
        self.set_location(self.position[0], self.position[1])

    def object_down(self):
        self.position[1] -= 20
        self.set_location(self.position[0], self.position[1])

    def update_pos(self):
        self.set_location(self.position[0] + self.direction[0],
                          self.position[1] + self.direction[1])

    def border_check(self, max_height=290, max_width=380):
        self.update_coordinates()
        if self.position[1] > max_height:
            self.set_location(self.position[0], max_height)
            self.direction[1] *= -1
            return False
        if self.position[1] < -1 * max_height:
            self.set_location(self.position[0], -1 * max_height)
            self.direction[1] *= -1
            return False
        if self.position[0] > max_width:
            self.set_location(0, 0)
            self.direction[0] *= -1
            return True
        if self.position[0] < -1 * max_width:
            self.set_location(0, 0)
            self.direction[0] *= -1
            return True

window = turtle.Screen()
window.title("Pong 2021 by Stephan Randle the Developer")
window.bgcolor("black")
window.setup(width=800, height=600)
window.tracer(0)

paddle_a = PongObj(-350, 0)
paddle_b = PongObj(350, 0)
ball = PongObj(0, 0, 1, 1, .2)

window.listen()
window.onkeypress(paddle_a.object_up, "w")
window.onkeypress(paddle_a.object_down, "s")
window.onkeypress(paddle_b.object_up, "Up")
window.onkeypress(paddle_b.object_down, "Down")

while True:
    window.update()

    ball.update_pos()
    if ball.border_check():
        if ball.direction[0] > 0:
            paddle_a.score += 1
            print(f"score for a: {paddle_a.score}")
        else:
            paddle_b.score += 1
            print(f"score for b: {paddle_b.score}")
```

Comment: You've defined all your attributes as class attributes (meaning they're shared by all instances of that class -- hence when you change one object's position, they *all* change).  You want them instead to be instance attributes (defined in `__init__`).

Comment: Object-orientation has nothing to do with whether an approach is "linear" or not. You are probably thinking of [imperative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_programming) vs [event-driven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming)  programming (which have nothing to do with object-orientation)

Comment: Then please mark it as duplciate

Comment: thank you everyone I see the error I made now. I'm not used to pythons syntax. and whatnot. @Samwise this was what my issue was